# npm start error expressjs server with mongodb

Tags: javascript, express

npm start in windows was fine. but in macos is leading to the error below.

```
> node ./bin/www.js

www error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
```

please let me know if any info needed

Comment: Can u write `node -v` in your mac OS console and add the output, this may be beneficial

Comment: It's hard to tell what `?` you are trying to use because you failed to provide a [mcve], but the solution will be: Upgrade Node so that it is both (a) at least as new as the version you have installed on the Windows machine and (b) at least the oldest version of Node.js that is actually supported.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Ameer for pointing out the possible issue. it is fixed after updating the node version.

`$ node -v` `v10.24.1`

to

`$ node -v` `v16.8.0`